# angularjs directive required attribute for inner control

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am struggling with the following problem. We have a directive called deeplink. It has the following code:

```js
restrict: 'E',
require: 'ngModel',
scope: {
    smDropdown: '=smDeeplinkDropdown',
    settings: '&smDropdownSettings',
    onRefresh: '&smOnRefresh',
    onModelChange: "&?smOnChange",
    disable: "=?",
    valueRequired: "=?",
    hideNew: "=?",
    excludeValue : "=?"
},
templateUrl: 'app/templates/smDeeplinkDropdown',
```

And the template for the directive is the following:

```html
<div class="row input-group">
    <select name="deeplinkDropdown"
            class="form-control dropdown deeplinkDropdown"
            ng-disabled="disable"
            ng-required="valueRequired"
            data-ng-model="dropdownModel.key"
            data-ng-options="item.key as item.text disable when item.hidden for item in itemList | filter:ngOptionFilter"
            data-ng-change="modelChanged(dropdownModel.key)">
        <option value="">{{noneSelectedLabel}}</option>
    </select>
```

I only show the relevant info here, not the whole HTML or whole code. Anyway, I'm struggling with the required attribute for that select. In my form I have the following:

```html
<div data-sm-deeplink-dropdown="crud.metaData.vendors"
     data-ng-model="crud.model.vendorId"

     value-required="true"
     name="vendorId"
     id="vendorId"
     data-sm-dropdown-settings="crud.getVendorSettings()"
     data-sm-on-refresh="crud.refreshMetaData()">
</div>
<label class="field-validation-error control-label-error animate-show"
       ng-show="form.editPurchaseOrdersGeneralForm.vendorId.$error.required">
    @string.Format(Messages.isRequired, Labels.vendor)
</label>
```

My problem is that the select control doesn't propagate its required error back to the main directive element. So, I can not really see my validation error.

While I was writing this I thought I can probably add an ng-form either in my form or inside the directive to solve this problem. I don't really like adding too many ng-forms but I see no other solution.

What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, in my form I simply changed div to ng-form and this worked (except for original form loading - it only shows in red with my error when I change to something and then to empty option)

Comment: Usually you don't want to slow errors before the user has touched or submitted the form

Comment: I want the red color right away, but I will display the validation error only if the control is dirty.

Comment: Well that's not what the defaults are but you can customize them. I recommend you look into angular formly. It's a great library

Comment: It looks like ng-required only works (e.g. displays control in red color) if I change to something and then back to nothing. We did have similar issue with just regular drop down with ng-required attribute. Is it the expected behavior?